# News Post and Users Relationshp With Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm attempting to make a relationship with my users table and my news_posts table. When I look at the queries that are ran it shows the followoing.

```
select * from `news_posts` where `news_posts`.`deleted_at` is null and `id` = '1' limit 1
select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`id` is null limit 1
```

So I'm trying to figure out why its saying NULL for the user.id.

I'm trying to access $news_post->author->first_name and $news_post->author->first_name.

[My Laravel Pastebin](http://laravel.io/bin/Bd495#27)

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('NewsPost', 'user_id');
    }
}

class NewsPost extends \Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $table = 'news_posts';

    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    // DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS --------------------------------------------------
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('NewsCategory');
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}


table: news_posts
fields: id, user_id, title, content

table: users
fields: id, username, first_name, last_name
```

Comment: And where's the code you have to run those queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (NewsPost::all() as $news_post)
{
    echo $news_post->author->name;
}
```